# How to get properties from gradle.properties into application.yaml

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, yaml

I have multi-project structure with gradle, and use `gradle.properties` file to store environment variables.
Also I use SpringBoot application environment with `application.properties` file at some number of projects.
At `gradle.properties` file I have `api.port=8080`, to get it at `application.properties` file I use `@api.port@` value, i.e. `@..@` placeholders like at official documentation.
Which placeholders I should use if I rename `application.properties` to `application.yaml`?
I tried to use:
`server:
  port: @api.port@`
`server: 
   port: '@api.port@'`
`server: 
   port: ${api.port}`
If I rename `gradle.properties` into `gradle.yaml`, it occures error with properties reading at `build.gradle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is simple, earlier I used this with properties files, and now simple read own code more carrier:

```
processResources {
        filesMatching('application.yaml') {
            filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                    'api.port'         : project.property('api.port')
            ]
        }
    }
```